# Referring exploded war dependency in maven antrun plugin

Tags: maven-2

I have a dependency declared as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

This war file which is part of an ear is exploded in the target directly and I need to copy a file(version.properties) to the WEB-INF/classes folder of this exploded war directory (target/mywebapp-1.3.2.war/). How can I refer to this folder in the antrun plugin without any hardcoding? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to cheat a bit and ask that you declare the dependency like this, with references to [properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${war.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${war.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${war.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

and the properties would look something like this in your pom.

```
<properties>
    <war.groupId>com.abc.webapp</war.groupId>
    <war.artifactId>mywebapp</war.artifactId>
    <war.version>1.3.2</war.version>
</properties>
```

Now, you still need to change the war GAV if required, but you only need to do it once, and the `<dependency>` and copy will both refer to the same thing.

Then maybe you could also use the maven-resouces-plugin and its [copy-resource](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) goal.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${war.artifactId}-${war.version}.war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>
              <directory>where_version.properties_is</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>version.properties</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```